# Why do generic parameters need to be cast to object before cast to specific type?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, .net-4.6.1

Why is the intermediate cast to `object` necessary?

I'm wondering why the compiler team designed it this way.

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeMethod(new Test());
        }

        public static void SomeMethod<T>(T someParam)
        {
            var x = (Test)(object)someParam; //This compiles
            //var x = (Test)someParam; //This doesn't compile: Cannot convert type 'T' to 'ConsoleApp4.Test'
        }
    }

    class Test
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: In short, you are misusing *generics*. The object cast is a way to say, "all bets are off". Use it at your own risk.

Comment: Its also worth to note, If you are checking for types and/or casting like this in a generic context, there is a more than good chance you need an appropriate *constraint* or *generics* is the wrong tool for the job

Comment: Perhaps you want to [apply a constraint to the generic type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) so that only Test and its derivatives are accepted?

Comment: @Llama this is just a contrived example. I just want to know why the intermediate object cast is necessary.

Comment: @TheGeneral couldn't you use that same logic for T as well? If it's a T, it could be any type (same with object).

Comment: Not really, Generics are a compile time construct for which the compiler and developer can reason about its contract. an Unconstrainted T is exactly that, there is no reasoning. it is just a placeholder with a minimal contract. When you cast T, the compiler is smart enough not to let you shoot yourself in the foot, by casting T in to object there isn't much static analysis can help you with, your code is now capable of runtime errors, you have taken the reigns and on a one way street to errortown.  Type checking is a slightly different problem, however its born from the same design issue

Comment: .NET knows that an instance of `T` can be cast as `object` (no matter that `T` actually represents), and that `Test` can be held by an `object`, therefore it needs to be possible to cast back. What .NET doesn't know, is if `T` is derived from, or an instance of, `Test`. Therefore, no possible cast is known to .NET.

Comment: Note that you'll still get a runtime `InvalidCastException` if `T` can't be cast to `Test`.  All you've done with adding `(object)` is working around the compiler's static type checking.

Comment: While I agree with Peter Duniho that "why compiler team decided to do X" is generally opinion base we already have answer by representative from the compiler team - so duplicate is reasonable resolution from my point of view here.